# Style CSS in Selector in Chrome Browser

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a form with a `<select>` element. The background is black, but in some browser there aren't any problem. Because the square around the arrow is white. But in Chrome, this square gets the same color (black) and the arrow can't be seen.

How can I change the color of the square around the arrow in selectors with CSS?

```css
.years{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #111111;
    border: 1px solid #444444;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #CCCCCC;
    height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    padding: 0.15em;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select class="years" name="years">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1y">1 year</option>
    <option value="3ys">3 years</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5vW6z/)

Comment: please could you provide a fiddle? What do you mean by "form with a selector" ? do you mean "select" ?

Comment: You mean `<select>` element, right? Just checking...

Comment: yes sorry, <select> element

Comment: can you make example on jsfiddle?

Comment: Did you add -webkit-appearance: none; ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5vW6z/

Comment: If I add -webkit-appearance:none the arrow disappear :/

Answer (score 0):

Select elements are *hard* to style, especially arrow part.

Usual workaround is something like this:

```
<div class="customSelect">
    <select>
        <option>I like StackOverflow</option>
        <option disabled>Nah, I don't</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

set `width` to `select` slightly more than `.customSelect`'s, then apply `overflow:hidden` and attach background image (arrow image) to `.customSelect` and set position (`right:0`).